# MySQL update query hangs indefinitely - can't figure out why

Tags: mysql

I have an update query that hangs forever when I run it and I can't figure out why.

Here is the query:

```sql
UPDATE    DWH_RAP215.`DWH_RAP215` a 
LEFT JOIN DWH_RAP215.`TMP_KANNIS038` b ON a.`pht` = b.`PHT`
SET a.`Vectoring_indication` = b.`Vectoring_indication`;
```

The tables involved in the update has 5.7 million and 4 million rows each.

Both tables have indexes on the join columns.

Below is the InnoDB monitor message I get while this query is running:

> TRANSACTION 0 0, not started, process no 8368, OS thread id 140468180481792 MySQL thread id 3979, query id 89130064 144.44.16.179 bugar500
>
> Sending data `` UPDATE   DWH_RAP215.`DWH_RAP215` a LEFT JOIN DWH_RAP215.`TMP_KANNIS038` b ON a.`pht` = b.`PHT` SET a.`Vectoring_indication` = b.`Vectoring_indication ``
>
> -------- FILE I/O --------
>
> I/O thread 0 state: waiting for i/o request (insert buffer thread) I/O
>
> thread 1 state: waiting for i/o request (log thread) I/O
>
> thread 2 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread) I/O
>
> thread 3 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
>
> Pending normal aio reads: 0, aio writes: 0,  ibuf aio reads: 0, log i/o's: 0, sync i/o's: 0
>
> Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0 1341 OS file reads, 7 OS file writes, 7 OS fsyncs 0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 0.00 writes/s, 0.00 fsyncs/s
>
> ------------------------------------- INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX -------------------------------------
>
> Ibuf: size 1, free list len 38, seg size 40, 0 inserts, 0 merged recs, 0 merges Hash table size 17393, node heap has 0 buffer(s) 0.00 hash searches/s, 0.00 non-hash searches/s
>
> --- LOG ---
>
> Log sequence number 52 234205131
>
> Log flushed up to   52 234205131
>
> Last checkpoint at  52 234205131
>
> 0 pending log writes, 0 pending chkp writes 10 log i/o's done, 0.00 log i/o's/second
>
> ---------------------- BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY ----------------------
>
> Total memory allocated 20420456; in additional pool allocated 1046272
>
> Dictionary memory allocated 287160
>
> Buffer pool size   512
>
> Free buffers       0
>
> Database pages     512
>
> Modified db pages  0
>
> Pending reads 0
>
> Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
>
> Pages read 1373, created 0, written 1 0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
>
> No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
>
> -------------- ROW OPERATIONS --------------
>
> 0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue 1 read views open inside InnoDB
>
> Main thread process no. 8368, id 140468427413248, state: waiting for server activity
>
> Number of rows inserted 0, updated 0, deleted 0, read 5933 0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s
>
> ---------------------------- END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT ============================

Create statements of the 2 tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `TMP_KANNIS038` (
   `Vectoring_indication` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
   `PHT` varchar(17) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
   KEY `IDX1` (`PHT`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `DWH_RAP215` (
   `pht` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   `cgb` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
   `CGB_NAAM_VERKORT` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
   `postcode` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
   `huisnummer` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
   `huisnummer_toevoeging` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
   `BUURT_NAAM` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
   `WIJK_NAAM` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
   `GEMEENTE` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
   `WOONPLAATS` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
   `Rayon` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   `LOGISCHE_KABELCODE` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
   `lengte_1` int(7) DEFAULT NULL,
   `kvd_1` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
   `LOGISCHE_KABELCODE_1` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
   `lengte_2` int(7) DEFAULT NULL,
   `kvd_2` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
   `LOGISCHE_KABELCODE_2` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
   `lengte_3` int(7) DEFAULT NULL,
   `lengte_4` int(7) DEFAULT NULL,
   `totale_lengte` int(7) DEFAULT NULL,
   `INVOERKABEL` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
   `DADER_NUMMER` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
   `STIJL_HVD` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
   `CASSETTE_HVD` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
   `STIFT_HVD` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
   `STIJL_AFGAAND_1` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
   `STIFT_AFGAAND_1` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
   `STIJL_AFGAAND_2` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
   `STIFT_AFGAAND_2` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
   `INVOERADER` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
   `MANPUNT_CODE_EK` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
   `MANPUNT_TYPE_EK` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
   `LOGISCHE_KABELCODE_EK` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
   `VOEDENDE_KVD` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
   `Cable-Piece-Number` smallint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
   `Location-Code-Up` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
   `Location-Code-Down` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
   `Capacity` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
   `X` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `Y` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `Trilink` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
   `Vectoring_indication` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
   KEY `IDX1` (`pht`),
   KEY `IDX2` (`cgb`),
   KEY `IDX3` (`postcode`,`huisnummer`),
   KEY `IDX5` (`LOGISCHE_KABELCODE_EK`),
   KEY `IDX6` (`DADER_NUMMER`),
   KEY `IDX7` (`Rayon`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Explain plan:

```sql
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  a   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    5735243 
1   SIMPLE  b   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    4027111
```

Please help.

Comment: - How many records does your query affect? Also share the EXPLAIN plan and list of indexes from affected tables.

Comment: Provide CREATE TABLE for both tables. Try correlated subquery instead of JOIN.

Comment: Added create statements and explain plan in main text.

Comment: Your explain plan shows that no index is used and the CREATE TABLE statements contain the cause: you're using different character sets for column pht.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).